# VS Code language mode defaulting to Java not Apex

Tags: apex, vs-code

Every time I open an Apex class file (.cls) I have to manually change the language mode from Java to Apex. In VS Code settings I already have Language Detection enabled. Why does it not go by the filename extension?

Comment: Is the Salesforce Extension Bundle installed? Are you in a sfdx project? Did you let the extensions load?

Comment: Yes, "Salesforce Extension Pack" is installed. Yes the files are in an SFDX project. Yes extensions are all loaded.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have your association settings set up incorrectly. This can happen if you have other extensions installed that might think .cls is Java, C#, or whatever else. To fix this, open Settings (File | Preferences | Settings), choose "User" (affects all workspaces you open) or "Workspace" (affects just the current workspace), find "files.associations", and add an entry for `*.cls` mapped to `apex`. This will override the default mappings that may have been configured by extensions you have installed. See the [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/overview) if you need more info.

Comment: Thank you! That was the solution. So simple.